# Order by in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table zipcode which look like this

```
  Code      State    Region        Distance
  25696      1       5             150
  25692      1       4             60 
  25691      2       3             50
  25690      2       2             233
  25688      3       4             450
  25686      3       5             560
  25685      4       7             50 
  12069      4       8             30
  12068      4       5             60
  12067      6       3             80
  12066      7       1             90
```

Now i want to sort this data like if state 4 is selected then first order by State 4 Regions then by Distance then the rest, regardless of region, sorted by distance.

So result should be this

```
  Code      State    Region        Distance
  12068      4       5             60
  25685      4       7             50 
  12069      4       8             30
  25691      2       3             50
  25692      1       4             60
  12067      6       3             80
  12066      7       1             90 
  25696      1       5             150
  25690      2       2             233
  25690      2       2             233
  25686      3       5             560
```

First State 4 regions in ascending order then rest date sorted by distance regardless of region , states.

I m trying following query

```
    SELECT region,br.state, case when state = 4 then -1
                          else state end as StateOrder,

  FROM zipcode 
  ORDER BY StateOrder,region, Distance asc;
```

This query gives State 4 regions first in sorted order but rest data is also sorted with state and region and this need to fix.

Please suggest.

Comment: ORDER BY FIELD(region,4) [DESC] ,distance;   ?

Comment: Sorry Not getting this..

Comment: Can you post what you want as the result based on your sample?

Comment: Edited my question, please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM zipcode 
 ORDER  
    BY FIELD(state,4) DESC
     , CASE WHEN state=4 THEN region END
     , distance;
```

Comment: This works absolutely fine...thanks....

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CASE` expression in your `ORDER BY`:

```
select code, state, region, distance
from zipcode
order by 
  case when state = 4 then region else distance end
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/100d6/1)